# Multiple Datasets in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am new to chart.js and I want to have multiple datasets in my bar chart, here is the initial view of the chart:

[image]

```
  var xValues = ["Below 13", "14 - 20", "21 - 40", "41- 50", "51 and above"];
                                var yValues = [55, 49, 44, 34, 45];
                                var barColors = [
                                    "#b91d47",
                                    "#00aba9",
                                    "#2b5797",
                                    "#e8c3b9",
                                    "#1e7145"
                                ];

                                new Chart("myChart", {
                                    type: "bar",
                                    data: {

                                        labels: xValues,
                                        datasets: [{
                                                backgroundColor: "#b91d47",
                                                data: [55],
                                                label: 'Purok 1'

                                            },

                                        ],

                                    },

                                    

                                });
```

I want to add another blue bar for the next column for the 14 - 20.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another dataset in the `datasets` array of your chart configuration. Each dataset represents a different bar in the chart.

I modified the code part into this;

```
new Chart("myChart", {
   type: "bar",
   data: {
       labels: xValues,
       datasets: [{
           backgroundColor: barColors[0],
           data: [55],
           label: 'Purok 1'
       }, {
           backgroundColor: barColors[1],
           data: [49],
           label: 'Purok 2'
       }],
   },
});
```

I've added a second dataset for the **"14 - 20"** category. The `backgroundColor` property is set to the second color in your `barColors` array, and the `data` property is set to the second value in your `yValues` array. The `label` property is set to **'Purok 2'** to differentiate this bar from the first one.

You can add as many datasets as you need to represent all the categories in your chart. Just make sure that the `backgroundColor`, `data`, and `label` properties are set correctly for each dataset.

Remember that the order of the datasets in the `datasets` array corresponds to the order of the bars in the chart. The first dataset will be the first bar, the second dataset will be the second bar, and so on.